# Get first non-empty cell that matches a value in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with 2 columns: Invoice Number and Invoice Amount.

[image: Excel Image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/52kUj.png)]

The first column (Invoice Number) has many duplicates, and the second column (Invoice Amount) has only empty cells except there is one amount that matches the sum of the invoices.

I have already consolidated all of the unique Invoice Number values into another sheet and now I am trying to add all of their corresponding Invoice Amounts to that sheet as well.

I have tried many `VLOOKUP`, `MATCH`, `INDEX`, `IFERROR` functions and cannot get this to work.

Whatever function I try, fails because it only returns the empty cell that matches.

For instance, in the image I would want to do a VLOOKUP or related function that can return '2462.87' for every row with the Invoice Number '1891936'.

Comment: If you first convert the column B values to numbers (e.g. enter 1 in a blank cell, copy it, _Paste Special_ with column B selected, and choose _Multiply_) then, based on there being only one total per invoice in column B, `=SUMIF($A$1:$A$1000,1891936,$B$1:$B$1000)` assuming you have data only in 1000 rows

Comment: That would work, I apologize there are some random times where the total appears 2 or 3 times and this spans 8,000 rows so it'd be very tedious to clean that up. I appreciate the response though.

Comment: Ok, assuming the invoice you want to reference is in cell `E1`, `SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8000=E1)*(--$B$1:$B$8000)/SUMPRODUCT(--((($A$1:$A$8000=E1)*($B$1:$B$8000))>0)))`

Comment: Or, if you happen to have Microsoft 365, `--TAKE(SORT(FILTER(B1:B8000,A1:A8000=E1),,-1),1)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your data by columns B, C.
2. Do a VLOOKUP
3. The first line with a new `Invoice Number` also holds the `invoice_amount`, therefore the VLOOKUP returns what you need.

[image: After sorting]

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this approach: instead of looking for that one cell which contains the value you're looking for, just sum everything together: if a cell is not filled in, the value is zero and it does not impact the sum anyway.

As a result, you get something like in the following sheet:

[image: Excel screenshot]

The used formula is `=SUMIF(A$2:A$16,D2,B$2:B$16)`.